# How to convert a URI to an integer drawable and add it to int[] array of drawables?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have an array of integers which stores drawables:

```
 menuIcons = new int[] {R.drawable.icon_default,R.drawable.icn_delete_45x45,
    R.drawable.icn_delete_45x45,R.drawable.icn_delete_45x45 };
```

I use this array to populate images in my list. Now the problem scenario is that for the first row I dont have an image in the draable folder but I have a URI in my database, this URI can refer to a server URL or a local URI on the SDCard or even a content provider URI. I have a function to handle displaying images from various sources.

The problem here is that I dont know how to add this URI at position 0 of my int array of drawables, or is that even possible?

As a duct-tape solution I can pass this URI to my constructor of the ListAdapter Class and detect the position 0 and display the image accordingly. But that is not a proper solution.

Answer (score 2):

it's impossible to do what you want as an array of resource id's. The reason is simple: the image you refer to is located elsewhere and does not belong to your app's statical resources.

UPDATE:

you could start with something like:

```
Object[] menuIcons = { "some://uri", "some://other_uri", R.drawable.icon_default,R.drawable.icn_delete_45x45,
R.drawable.icn_delete_45x45,R.drawable.icn_delete_45x45 };

List<Drawable> drawables = new ArrayList<>();

for( Object ic : menuIcons ){
  switch( ic.getClass().getSimpleName() ){
    case "int":
    case "Integer":
      drawables.add( getResources().getDrawable( (int)ic );
      break;

    case "String":
      drawables.add( getDrawableFromSomeUri( (String)ic ) );
      break;

    case "URL":
      drawables.add( getDrawableFromSomeURL( (URL)ic ) );
      break;

  }
}
```

instead of a `List` you could use a `Map` to simplify lookup

Comment: So unfortunately, I will have to go with the Duct tape solution

Comment: Any heading on that? A link perhaps?